# Cannot load json file in python

Tags: python, json

I got a file of twitter streaming data in json. Now I'm trying to load it in python:

```
import json

tweets_data=[]
tweets_file=open('test1.txt',"r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet=json.load(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue 

print(len(tweets_data))
```

The result is always 0. If "try" and "except" are removed, then error is "ValueError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)". However, each line of the file is a valid JSON according to online validator.

Here is a segment of test1.txt:

```
{"created_at":"Fri Jul 24 16:35:22 +0000 2015","id":624618886277640192,"id_str":"624618886277640192","text":"RT @nodenow: Essential Steps: Long Term Support for Node.js\nhttp:\/\/t.co\/MzPfvenwtT\n+1 micshasan #javascript","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3290861609,"id_str":"3290861609","name":"Rajiin","screen_name":"Rajiin_07","location":"Pokhara city","url":"http:\/\/www.pokharacity.com","description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1101,"friends_count":1119,"listed_count":155,"favourites_count":2048,"statuses_count":5498,"created_at":"Wed May 20 04:58:23 +0000 2015","utc_offset":-25200,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"4A913C","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/617620457336893440\/3HTEKnMx_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/617620457336893440\/3HTEKnMx_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3290861609\/1435854327","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Fri Jul 24 16:33:04 +0000 2015","id":624618308050915328,"id_str":"624618308050915328","text":"Essential Steps: Long Term Support for Node.js\nhttp:\/\/t.co\/MzPfvenwtT\n+1 micshasan #javascript","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3243544179,"id_str":"3243544179","name":"Javascript Digest","screen_name":"nodenow","location":"","url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1238,"friends_count":1,"listed_count":1148,"favourites_count":2,"statuses_count":130923,"created_at":"Sat May 09 15:45:13 +0000 2015","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/597066594334941184\/Xe4tTtU8_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/597066594334941184\/Xe4tTtU8_normal.jpg","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":1,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"javascript","indices":[83,94]}],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/MzPfvenwtT","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1LH81ly","display_url":"bit.ly\/1LH81ly","indices":[47,69]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"javascript","indices":[96,107]}],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/MzPfvenwtT","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1LH81ly","display_url":"bit.ly\/1LH81ly","indices":[60,82]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"nodenow","name":"Javascript Digest","id":3243544179,"id_str":"3243544179","indices":[3,11]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1437755722003"}


{"created_at":"Fri Jul 24 16:35:22 +0000 2015","id":624618888387432449,"id_str":"624618888387432449","text":"python \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430  http:\/\/t.co\/itYJmgVvgD","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/gdepraktika.ru\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003egdepraktika-trfnslator\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":623605809,"id_str":"623605809","name":"\u0413\u0434\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430?","screen_name":"gdepraktika","location":"\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f","url":"http:\/\/gdepraktika.ru","description":"\u041f\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430, \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0436\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430, \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0441\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432, \u043e\u0431\u0443\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0432 \u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f\u0445","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":17,"friends_count":9,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":902069,"created_at":"Sun Jul 01 07:53:36 +0000 2012","utc_offset":10800,"time_zone":"Moscow","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"ru","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000420815111\/bba61a6dcd4272794a4af41dd8a44cf5_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000420815111\/bba61a6dcd4272794a4af41dd8a44cf5_normal.png","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/itYJmgVvgD","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1GqpqOg","display_url":"bit.ly\/1GqpqOg","indices":[15,37]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"und","timestamp_ms":"1437755722506"}
```

Comment: Which line causes the problem?

Comment: The empty lines are valid json?  Actually none of what you have posted looke valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because there are two blank lines between the valid json lines. Just add a check for blank lines and you should be good to go.

```
import json
tweets_data = []
notParsed = []
tweets_file = open('test1.txt',"r")
for line in tweets_file:    
    if line.strip():    
        try:
            tweet=json.load(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
        except:
            notParsed.append(line)
            continue
print(len(tweets_data))
print('Could not parse: ', len(notParsed))
```

This isn't required and I'm just revising Python because of your answer, but you could edit your code as follows:

`map(json.loads, [x for x in open('test1.txt').read().split('\n') if x.strip()])`

Comment: is there a Python module that is as clever at loading those jsons as the typical online validator?  This is not the first time I have http://jsonlint.com/ return success only to have  **json** module choke.

Comment: @JLPeyret, well, an empty line is not valid JSON, regardless how clever the parser is.

Comment: If the json cannot be parsed it should not be ignored

Comment: Fair point, though the OP had ignored them anyway.  Added a notifier for that too.

Comment: Great! Just tried "notParsed()" and every line is "not parsed"...  And your solution rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, your segment doesn't look like valid json after all.  (And copy-pasting it into the validator http://jsonlint.com confirms that.  Syntatically, there needs to be a comma between the two tweets, and the reason is that they need to be elements in some higher-level data structure (the json-equivalent of a python list == an "array," or the json-equivalent of a dict, an "object").  There can be only one root element in a json file.  See this prior question: [How to read a JSON file containing multiple root elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639886/how-to-read-a-json-file-containing-multiple-root-elements).

Second, if you're trying to just get ordinary access to the json data structure, and aren't trying to do anything special that depends on the notion of a line (or worrying about memory management, etc.), then you don't really need to read it in line by line like this.  Instead, you can just bind the whole shebang to a variable, and it will turn the json into nested lists and dicts according to the obvious syntax (i.e., the json curlybraces/brackets function the same as the python ones).

So once you get the json valid, the code can be as simple as:

```
import json
with open('test1.txt') as json_file:
  myjson = json.load(json_file)
```

then just access every element in the json via list indexes/dict keys.

This method ignores whitespace, so you should have no problem with the line breaks.

Ultimately, this suggests that the solution is to wrap your tweets in a top-level list ("array") and stick commas between them (maybe with regexes as a string operation?), then just access them by list indexing rather than going line by line.

Answer (score -1):

a line may has \r \n space .etc
and you should use `json.loads()`

```
import json

tweets_data=[]
tweets_file=open('test1.txt',"r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet=json.loads(line.strip())
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

print(len(tweets_data))
```

Comment: `{ "whitespaces" : "are", "ignored": "in", "JSON": "data" }`. But an empty input is not valid JSON.

Comment: @张文辉, Yes I tried loads() but it shows "ValueError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)"