# How to validate JSON having multiple root elements

Tags: java, json

I am having a [c](/questions/tagged/c)code, which bulids [json](/questions/tagged/json)file in the below format.

```
{"swap":1,"si":11},{"system":1,host:"new"},{"Cpu":1}
```

If I validate this [json](/questions/tagged/json)file data i get an error as:

> Parse error on line 4:
>
> ...": 1,    "si": 11},{    "system": 1,
>   ---------------------^ Expecting 'EOF'

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the reason that you cannot give it a root element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a JSON file containing multiple root elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639886/how-to-read-a-json-file-containing-multiple-root-elements)

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Also, having multiple root elements is not valid JSON, so parsing should break

Comment: In JSON every key is double quoted. Your json is missing double quotes at host key.

{
    "system": 1,
    "host": "new"
}

Answer (score 1):

Wrap those [json](/questions/tagged/json)Objects in to an `JsonArray` while building. Then in [java](/questions/tagged/java) iterate through the [json](/questions/tagged/json)array.

Answer (score 1):

In [json](/questions/tagged/json)every key is double quoted `"key"`. Your [json](/questions/tagged/json)is missing double quotes at host key. Make sure you're writing a well-formed [json](/questions/tagged/json).

```
{ "system": 1, "host": "new" }
               ^    ^
```

Answer (score 1):

am not a expert in JSON but i think you want to change a JSON like array value

```
[{"swap":1,"si":11},{"system":1,host:"new"},{"Cpu":1}]
```

insted of

```
{"swap":1,"si":11},{"system":1,host:"new"},{"Cpu":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this custom function even if you have complex objects.

```
static getParsedJson(jsonString) {
    const parsedJsonArr = [];
    let tempStr = '';
    let isObjStartFound = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonString.length; i += 1) {
        if (isObjStartFound) {
            tempStr += jsonString[i];
            if (jsonString[i] === '}') {
                try {
                    const obj = JSON.parse(tempStr);
                    parsedJsonArr.push(obj);
                    tempStr = '';
                    isObjStartFound = false;
                } catch (err) {
                    // console.log("not a valid JSON object");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isObjStartFound && jsonString[i] === '{') {
            tempStr += jsonString[i];
            isObjStartFound = true;
        }
    }
    return parsedJsonArr;
}
```