# JSON.parse error while writing json data into json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-handling, python-jsonschema

I am trying to get JSON data from a localhost URL row by row and insert it into a JSON file. When I try to open the file, I receive an error that says `Multiple JSON root elements`.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request, json 
import json
abc={}

for i in range(6666,6669):
    print(i)
    full_url="http://localhost/get/info" + str(i)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(full_url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        print(data['id'])
    abc={i:[data]}
    with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(abc,outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid json object must have only one root

See [How to read a JSON file containing multiple root elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639886/how-to-read-a-json-file-containing-multiple-root-elements)

You must append all json objects to an array and then write it to the json file

Resulting json object must be like

```
[
{ object 1 },
{ object 2 }
]
```

notice that there's only one root object in the json, the array containing all of the other objects

Comment: actually i cannot get directly whole data in one object. in each iteration i got only one row information which i need to write in json file in one root.

Comment: i will try it to put first in array and then i will put that into json file