# Saving json file by dumping dictionary in a for loop, leading to malformed json

Tags: json, python-3.x

So I have the following dictionaries that I get by parsing a text file

```
keys = ["scientific name", "common names", "colors]
values = ["somename1", ["name11", "name12"], ["color11", "color12"]]

keys = ["scientific name", "common names", "colors]
values = ["somename2", ["name21", "name22"], ["color21", "color22"]]
```

and so on. I am dumping the key value pairs using a dictionary to a json file using a for loop where I go through each key value pair one by one

```
for loop starts
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    with open("file.json", 'a') as j:
        json.dump(d, j)
```

If I open the saved json file I see the contents as

```
{"scientific name": "somename1", "common names": ["name11", "name12"], "colors": ["color11", "color12"]}{"scientific name": "somename2", "common names": ["name21", "name22"], "colors": ["color21", "color22"]}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

The purpose is to query the common name or colors for a given scientific name. So then I do

```
with open("file.json", "r") as j:
    data = json.load(j)
```

I get the error, `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:`
I think this is because I am not dumping the dictionaries in json in the for loop correctly. I have to insert some square brackets programatically. Just doing `json.dump(d, j)` won't suffice.

Comment: Don't `a`ppend to the file. Make it one JSON document with a root array, then you can read in the current list, add to it and write the whole thing back out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are you saying that instead of appending, I create some list out of the dictionaries in the for loop and then write that list at the end to a json file...bit of a json novice here?

Comment: @ontherocks That's what I'd do at least in this situation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639886/how-to-read-a-json-file-containing-multiple-root-elements

Comment: @StamKaly Should the list be like `dictList = [dict1, dict2, dict3....]` and then `json.dump(dictList, j)`?

Comment: yeah, json can handle that just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON may only have one root element. This root element can be `[]`, `{}` or most other datatypes.

In your file, however, you get multiple root elements:

```
{...}{...}
```

This isn't valid JSON, and the error `Extra data` refers to the second `{}`, where valid JSON would end instead.

You can write multiple dicts to a JSON string, but you need to wrap them in an array:

```
[{...},{...}]
```

But now off to how I would fix your code. First, I rewrote what you posted, because your code was rather pseudo-code and didn't run directly.

```py
import json

inputs = [(["scientific name", "common names", "colors"],
           ["somename1", ["name11", "name12"], ["color11", "color12"]]),
          (["scientific name", "common names", "colors"],
           ["somename2", ["name21", "name22"], ["color21", "color22"]])]

for keys, values in inputs:
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    with open("file.json", 'a') as j:
        json.dump(d, j)

with open("file.json", 'r') as j:
    print(json.load(j))
```

As you correctly realized, this code failes with

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 105 (char 104)
```

The way I would write it, is:

```
import json

inputs = [(["scientific name", "common names", "colors"],
           ["somename1", ["name11", "name12"], ["color11", "color12"]]),
          (["scientific name", "common names", "colors"],
           ["somename2", ["name21", "name22"], ["color21", "color22"]])]

jsonData = list()
for keys, values in inputs:
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    jsonData.append(d)

with open("file.json", 'w') as j:
    json.dump(jsonData, j)

with open("file.json", 'r') as j:
    print(json.load(j))
```

Also, for python's `json` library, it is important that you write the entire json file in one go, meaning with `'w'` instead of `'a'`.

Comment: I populate the common names and colors list on the fly in the loop, and then after I create the dict object I clear the list so that those lists are re-populated with new values in the next for loop iteration. But then this also clears the value in the dict object (it behaves like pointers). I would have to create a shallow or deep copy instead of `jsonData.append(d)`, but I am not getting the syntax right. Would you have an idea?

Comment: I think this is a new and unrelated question, and should usually not be discussed in the comment section of a previous problem. Nonetheless, I think this should answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: Also, I don't think clearing the list is the right thing to do, just create a new list, then the old one lives on

Comment: And I'd appreciate to become the accepted answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: If I leave the old lists, the number of those lists would then be in 100 of thousands.  I have such big data. I may run out of memory.

Comment: It really doesn't make any difference, the json array still holds all of them anyways, if you copy them or not. So i think your point is invalid.
Also, 100 of thousands is not a lot. If it can't fit in memory, you can't fit it in a list, anyway.

Comment: If you are at the point where it doesn't fit in memory, I think JSON is the wrong file type. Consider an SQL database.

Comment: Or CSV, those are iterable and can be updated line by line, without having the entire file in memory. JSON can't.

Comment: Another solution I just found is the [.jsonl](http://jsonlines.org/) file format. There is even a [python library](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for it.

This might be exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks